# How to fetch API data with ReactNative and Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-ios

I'm creating this component for fetch data from "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json" file. I am trying this as a testing app and later planned to use my actual API endpoint. However, i'm struggling to show data in the screen. It doesn't give any error or show errors.How can i add activity Indicator to check whether data is fetching and  show data in ?

Action

```
import {
  FETCHING_ASSISTANT_REQUEST,
  FETCHING_ASSISTANT_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_ASSISTANT_FAILURE
} from "./types";

export function fetchAssistantRequest() {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_ASSISTANT_REQUEST
  };
}

export function fetchAssistantFailure(errorMessage) {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_ASSISTANT_FAILURE,
    errorMessage
  };
}

export const fetchAssistant = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchAssistantRequest());
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      dispatch(fetchAssistantSuccess(json.results));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchAssistantFailure(error));
    }
  };
};
```

Reducer

```
import {
  FETCHING_ASSISTANT_REQUEST,
  FETCHING_ASSISTANT_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_ASSISTANT_FAILURE
} from "../actions/types";

//initial states
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  errorMessage: null,
  assistant: []
};

export default function assistantReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    //fetching state
    case FETCHING_ASSISTANT_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, isFetching: true };
    //success state
    case FETCHING_ASSISTANT_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, assistant: action.data };
    //faliuer state
    case FETCHING_ASSISTANT_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, errorMessage: action.errorMessage };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

App Reducer

```
import .. from ".."
const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  // assis: AssistanceReduer,
  // assistant: DumyReducer,
  assis: AssisReducer
});

export default AppReducer;
```

App

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { fetchAssistant } from "../actions/AssistantAction";

class Assistant extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAssistance;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> {this.props.assistant.assistant.title}</Text>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.assistant.assistant.title)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    assistant: state.assis
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getAssistance: () => dispatch(fetchAssistant())
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Assistant);
```

STORE

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "remote-redux-devtools";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import AppReducer from "../reducers/AppReducer";

const store = createStore(
  AppReducer,
  {}, // initial state
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an untested solution, but it should work.
To show an activity indicator you have to use the isFetching variable in your redux store. Since "assistant" is an array, you have to use map() it to show every single item. A better solution would be a FlatList, of course.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { fetchAssistant } from "../actions/AssistantAction";

class Assistant extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAssistance();
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.isFetching) return (<ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" />);

    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.assistant.assistant.map(item => <Text key={item.id}>{item.title}</Text>)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isFetching: state.isFetching,
    assistant: state.assis
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getAssistance: () => dispatch(fetchAssistant())
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Assistant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well immediately it looks like your `fetchAssistantSuccess` function is not defined in your `Actions` file, so I am unsure how that *action* would be dispatched. You would need something like

**Action.js**

```
export function fetchAssistantSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_ASSISTANT_SUCCESS,
    payload
  };
}
```

and in your **Reducer.js**

```
case FETCHING_ASSISTANT_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, assistant: action.payload};
```

Also, you may want to test the endpoint separately in something like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)
to ensure it's passing the correct data.